# Difference between after_create, after_save and after_commit in rails callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, callback

The difference between `after_create`, `after_save` and `after_commit` in Rails is that:

- `after_save` is invoked when an object is created and updated
- `after_commit` is called on create, update and destroy.
- `after_create` is only called when creating an object

Is this the only difference among those, or are there any other major differences?

Comment: It not duplicate where is after_commit in that question?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You almost got it right. However there is one major difference between `after_commit` and `after_create` or `after_save` i.e.

In the case of `after_create`, this will always be before the call to save (or create) returns.

Rails wraps every save inside a transaction and the before/after create callbacks run inside that transaction (a consequence of this is that if an exception is raised in an after_create the save will be rolled back). With `after_commit`, your code doesn't run until after the outermost transaction was committed. This could be the transaction rails created or one created by you (for example if you wanted to make several changes inside a single transaction). Originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15753859/1381240)

That also means, that **if `after_commit` raises an exception, then the transaction won't be rolled back.**

From M-Dahab's comment:
`after_commit` would run after create, update and destroy. But, you can use `on:` option to specify which you are interested in. `after_commit :some_method, on: :create` or even `after_commit :some_method, on: [:create, :destroy]` or use a block like `after_commit(on: :update) do run_method() end`.

Comment: In the case of after_create, this will always be before the call to save (or create) returns. I am not able to understand this statement. Can anyone describe in other words?

Comment: `after_commit` would run after `create`, `update` and `destroy`. But, you can use `on:` option to specify which you are interested in.
`after_commit :some_method, on: :create` or even `after_commit :some_method, on: [:create, :destroy]` or use a block like `after_commit(on: :update) do run_method() end`.

Comment: Very useful to know when working with ActiveStorage, thanks.

Comment: There is a shorthand `after_save_commit :some_method` since rails 6+ that's equivalent to `after_commit :some_method, on: [:create, :destroy]`

Comment: would an exception in `after_save` halt the execution and cause the transaction rollback?

Answer (score 33):

With Order of callbacks

**after_create** -

Is called after Model.save on new objects that haven‘t been saved yet (no record exists)

**after_save** -

Is called after Model.save (regardless of whether it‘s a create or update save)

**after_commit** -

Is called after the database transaction is completed.

Answer (score 2):

Also, after_commit will execute even if the record was only touched.  This may NOT be what you want. after_save will not run after touch.