# Add an empty nested object to newly created user in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a User model in my Rails 5 app using Devise.

I also have a relationship: user belongs_to account.

Now, when I create a new user I want to automatically create a new empty account for it.

I already have my registrations controller and a method:

```
  def create
    super
  end
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
  def create
    super
    user.account.create()
  end
```

Comment: One thing you could do, is Account.create(user_id: @user.id). Maybe something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

In devise controllers, user object is called as `resource` by default. So something like this will work:

```
def create
  super
  if resource.persisted? # user has been created with no errors
    resource.account.create # assuming it will pass validations without arguments
  end
end
```

Another way, as @julien-js mentioned, is to create account in after-create hook, but instead of after_create you can use after_commit([read more about the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746362/after-create-foo-vs-after-commit-bar-on-create)):

```
after_commit :create_account, on: :create

def create_account
  self.account.create unless self.account.present?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that ?

In your model User.rb

```
after_create do
  self.account = Account.create()     if self.account.nil?
end
```